# Is there a way to find out which .NET Framework version uses which version of zlib? (in relation to CVE-2018-25032)

Tags: c#, .net, zlib

I'm trying to work out if we are exposed to the recently reported CVE-2018-25032 vulnerability, as .NET does use the zlib library in the DeflateStream implementation.

I can't seem to find anything released by Microsoft about this.

Is there a way to find out which .NET Framework version uses which version of zlib?

Comment: Not sure about the .NET Framework stuff but for .NET they compile it themselves and have a copy living in their repo at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/native/external/zlib. It seems to be version 1.2.11 though so it should be vulnerable (unless they patched it themselves). You would probably get a better answer by creating an issue over there though.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417244).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [DeflateStream docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream), .NET Framework versions prior to 4.5 do not use zlib at all:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the DeflateStream class uses the zlib library

I don't know which *exact* versions of zlib each subsequent version of .NET Framework used (and the version may have changed with minor patches over time), but I can give an approximation based on when each .NET Framework version was released and compare that to the latest version of zlib at the time (the .NET team most likely opted to use the latest version of each external library, including zlib, that was available at any given time):

| .NET Framework Version | Latest zlib version upon respective .NET version release |
| --- | --- |
| 4.5 | 1.2.7 |
| 4.5.1 | 1.2.8 |
| 4.5.2 | 1.2.8 |
| 4.6 | 1.2.8 |
| 4.6.1 | 1.2.8 |
| 4.6.2 | 1.2.8 |
| 4.7 | 1.2.11 |
| 4.7.1 | 1.2.11 |
| 4.8 | 1.2.11 |

As you can see, all versions of .NET Framework since zlib was added use a version of zlib that is susceptible to this CVE. [Per the author, Mark Adler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71760442/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-which-net-framework-version-uses-which-version-of-zl/71773404#comment126838545_71773404), however, DeflateStream may not even call `Z_FIXED` (see the CVE info below), so DeflateStream code may not be susceptible to the CVE despite the version of zlib it uses containing said vulnerability. If you have any custom code that does interact with `Z_FIXED` using .NET's packaged zlib version, you should mitigate the vulnerability manually or explicitly import zlib v1.2.12+ to overwrite .NET's built-in version.

Note that the CVE and zlib's patch for it are relatively new, and the latest version of .NET, .NET Core 6.0.6 (which was released on 14 June 2022), still uses zlib v1.2.11 (from 2017); .NET 7 is in Preview stages and likely (hopefully) will include v1.2.12+ by then; it doesn't look like .NET Core 6 as a major version will be updated to include a newer version.

From the .NET [zlib.3](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0e499ac03d4eacce9ce124f454d0ed4ac2cdafcd/src/native/external/zlib/zlib.3) file in the GitHub repository:

> ```
> .TH ZLIB 3 "15 Jan 2017"
> .SH NAME
> zlib \- compression/decompression library
> [...]
> ```

And zlib.h (the readme) from that same repository folder:

> ```
> /* zlib.h -- interface of the 'zlib' general purpose compression library
>   version 1.2.11, January 15th, 2017
> [...]
> ```

And from the [ZLIB changelog on GitHub](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/ChangeLog):

> ```
> ChangeLog file for zlib
>
> Changes in 1.2.12 (27 Mar 2022) 
> [...]
> - Fix a bug that can crash deflate on some input when using Z_FIXED 
> [...]
> ```

(Skipped irrelevant lines to focus on the specific change that was prompted by the CVE).

Comment: I don't see a way in the `DeflateStream` class to specify `Z_FIXED`.

Comment: Hi @MarkAdler -- to be clear, I have not used DeflateStream before, so I don't know how the .NET team's implementation of zlib works, regarding `Z_FIXED` or any aspect of the library. I am only providing the version information that OP asked for. The answer mentions DeflateStream only in the context that OP referenced it. If DeflateStream doesn't use Z_FIXED, then despite the zlib _version_ included in .NET having the vulnerability, code using DeflateStream may not itself be vulnerable at all... I'll update the answer to reflect that possibility.

Comment: Hi @TylerH, thank you very much for the very detailed answer. I will mark it as the answer. I'm surprised by Microsoft's lackadaisical approach to this vulnerability considering the amount of waves it's causing in the IT world. Hopefully this answer helps the next poor soul struggling with this issue (despite the strange downvotes). Also thank you for the support on the related meta question!